# C: no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gcc-warning

I was trying to compile some code using makefile

```
puzzle.o:
    gcc -o puzzle.o Sourcepuzzle -Wall -Werror -g
```

but a warning and an error saying that

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr 
ignored.
/usr/bin/ld: error in puzzle.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be 
created.
```

were returned and it failed to compile.

I tried to google about this and got the info to put `-fPIC -shared` besides the `-g` but it didn't solve the problem

I'm wondering why is this the problem and how should I solve this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Rename your source file, which is currently called `Sourcepuzzle`, to have the `.c` extension, like `source.c`.

Currently GCC seems unable to identify your program as C source and assumes it's C++. `.eh_frame` relates to C++ exceptions, and cannot be relevant if you have a C program.

Or if `Sourcepuzzle` is supposed to be a variable in your makefile, you need to use the variable's value in the command, i.e. `$(Sourcepuzzle)`. In this case it would also be recommended to name your makefile variable in uppercase, which is the accepted convention.